# How to place "spacer view"?

Tags: ios, uiview

I've read quite a bit about spacer views - they seem very handy in utilising all this auto layout stuff.

I understand all of the concepts behind them, that's fine... I'm looking to practice with them now but before I could even get started I've found myself getting stuck on a more fundamental issue that's really doing my head in... maybe I'm too tired.

How do I actually place a spacer view? I'm looking for some drag and drop, native kind of thingy... but I can't see any "spacer view" in the object browser.. do I have to create this view myself? Where does it come from?

Comment: What's a `Spacer View`??? I've never heard of them.

Comment: Look at this piece of their documentation and search for the term "spacer view": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

Comment: They referred to it a good many times but never explained it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacer views are just standard UIViews.

If you want to make them easier to use in IB then give them a coloured background and make them visible but in the runtime attributes give them a Boolean...

Hidden = YES;

That will hide them in the actual app.

The reason they are used with auto layout is because you can't create equal spaces. A space is the gap between two objects. It isn't an object itself so you can make two spaces equal (for example).

But you can replace the spaces by instances of UIView and now you can give these UIViews equal widths or heights. Make them hidden and the constraints still act on them but they cannot be seen.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple "UIView" widget you can drag and drop from the lower-right corner area of Interface Builder. I don't believe there's any official "spacer view" terminology in Apple's kit...

Comment: Are there any conventional settings I'm meant to apply to these views? Like... are they normally hidden? But then it makes it harder to use them in the storyboards because you can't see them... do you change a background? I dunno.. seems to be countless numbers of dodgy workarounds - I was just looking for something conventional. As commented in my question, I saw them refer to these "spacer view"s in their own documentation and that's what aroused my interest